# Toggling between links jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, animation

**JS:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <script type="text/javascript">
function slideUpAll(id){
 if(id != "about")
   $('#about').slideUp();
 if(id != "team")
   $('#team').slideUp();
 if(id != "contact")
   $('#contact').slideUp();
 if(id != "job")
   $('#job').slideUp();
}
function sd_about(){$('#about').slideDown("slow");}
function sd_team(){$('#team').slideDown("slow");}
function sd_contact(){$('#contact').slideDown("slow");}
function sd_job(){$('#job').slideDown("slow");}
$(function(){
  $("#about").delegate("anchorOrDivOrImg", "mousedown", function(e){

     slideUpAll(e.target.id);
  });
});
</script>
```

**html:**

```
        <div id="nav"> 
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="sd_about()">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="sd_team()">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="sd_contact()">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="sd_job()">Jobs</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
<div id="about">
        <div id="about_left">
            about
        </div><!--about_left--> 
        <div id="about_right">
            <img src="img/book.png" width="256" height="161" alt="LogicPad eBooks" />
        </div>

        <div id="clear"> </div>
</div><!--about-->
<div id="team">
<h1>team</h1>
</div>
<div id="contact">
<h1>contAct</h1>
</div>
<div id="job">
<h1>job</h1>
</div>
```

**What I'm trying to accomplish:** If you click one link, then click another link, the first link retracts and the last clicked link expands.

**What it's doing right now:** If you click one link, then click another link it basically just puts both sets of content one below another.

Can someone help me here? What am I doing wrong? Please show some source code in answer.

Comment: hmmmm - I can't see any links in your markup. Also I can't see any of the elements that your jQuery animations are referencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function slideUpAll(id){
 if(id != "about")
   $('#about').slideUp();
 if(id != "team")
   $('#team').slideUp();
 if(id != "contact")
   $('#contact').slideUp();
 if(id != "job")
   $('#job').slideUp();
}
function sd_about(){$('#about').slideDown("slow");}
function sd_team(){$('#team').slideDown("slow");}
function sd_contact(){$('#contact').slideDown("slow");}
function sd_job(){$('#job').slideDown("slow");}
$(function(){
  $("#about").delegate("anchorOrDivOrImg", "mousedown", function(e){

     slideUpAll(e.target.id);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What did you specify in the delegate selector?

Comment: I even dont know how you are calling those 4 functions.

Answer (score 0):

First give all of the parent navs a class, for example `nav`.

Then before each slideToggle, do `$(".nav").slideUp("slow")`

Comment: Well you have to post all of your code, you've only posted snippets.  Give me the full HTML/jQuery and then I'll be glad to help. a http://jsfiddle.net would be best.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your links, perhaps you can benefit from this jsfiddle example: [drop down menus](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/Wv4G2/).

I think perhaps you need to include a click function.  Right now, all I can see is that you have functions created but not called.  You have to either call the function from the link in onclick, or in jquery like this:

```
$('a').click(function(){ 
//code here 
});
```